# Getting "unable to cast PersistentGenericSet to ISet" error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapping

I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>       'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[IocWinFormTestEntities.People]' 
>       to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[IocWinFormTestEntities.People]'.

The entity:

```
public class Event 
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.People = new HashSet<People>();
    }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public virtual ISet<People> People { get; set; }
}
```

Map override class:

```
public class EventMapOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Event>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Event> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(c => c.People)
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

Generated hbm from fluent automapper:

```xml
<set cascade="all-delete-orphan" name="People">
    <key>
        <column name="Event_id" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="IocWinFormTestEntities.People, IocWinFormTestEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</set>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your problem is you are using [ISet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace but nHibernate expects ISet to be `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<>`. So change your property definition to

```
public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<People> People { get; set; }
```

If you want to use .net 4 `ISet<>` interface, go through this [article](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2011/03/15/using-lt-set-gt-in-mappings-without-iesi-collections-net-4.html)

Comment: Link redirects to home, seems to be dead.

Answer (score 14):

The latest NHibernate uses Iesi.Collections.ISet, not System.Collections.Generic.ISet. You can either reference the Iesi assembly or use System.Collections.Generic.ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<People> People { get; set; }
```

The ISet interface inherits from ICollection.

Comment: But last time I tried ICollection for <set>, NHib was always rewriting it with a plain Array instead of my original HashSet...

Answer (score 4):

With Nhibernate 4, using `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<>` is now [the way to go](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/nh-4-ga).

The error showcased in this question should no longer occur.