# Can .NET 4 ISet<> HashSet<> replace NHibernate Iesi.Collections ISet , HashSet?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, castle-windsor

Can .NET 4 ISet<>  HashSet<>  replace  NHibernate Iesi.Collections  ISet , HashSet ? I am using Castle proxy, and NHibernate 3.0 .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272636/nhibernate-unable-to-cast-persistentgenericset-to-iset

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not as of this reply.

The NHibernate engine uses the `Iesi.Collections.ISet` interface on internal collection classes which are used as wrappers around collections in your classes which NHibernate persists. There is no direct conversion to `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`.

***Update:*** NHibernate 4 now uses `HashSet<T>` from the BCL internally, and `HashedSet<T>` has been removed from the `Iesi.Collections` dependency. The approach to use `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>` is now available.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. There are two approaches:

1. Declare your collection as `ICollection<T>` and initialize it as
   `HashSet<T>`. See [this article](http://ayende.com/blog/3971/nhibernate-tidbit-using-set-without-referencing-iesi-collections). I model collections as private
   members and expose `IEnumerable<T>` so this works well, but the downside is that you can't expose `ISet<T>`.
2. Use Jose Romaniello's Set4Net4 NuGet package. See [this article](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/15/using-lt-set-gt-in-mappings-without-iesi-collections-net-4.aspx)
   and the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/jfromaniello/nhibernate.setfornet4).

Comment: Hm, when I tried it, NHib for some reason was recreating my collection as an Array, so I could not add/remove items. It just looked at ICollection and decided that it can put whatever it likes...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with Nhibernate 4, using `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<>` is now [the way to go](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/nh-4-ga).